# Published website: an attempt to attach an auto-named database for file...failed

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to publish a website with a locally stored database on my localhost. The problem is that I can't enter into any page who have a database embedded as a data source. All databases are kept into the App_Data folder, and I've used both into attachdbfilename:

```
1. |DataDirectory|/Database1.mdf
2. C:/Users/username/Desktop/websitefolder/App_Data/Database1.mdf
```

I've tried the other topics to solve my problem, but they are not mentioning that's a published website. The site works without any problem on localhost with the port assigned, but any page with a database/source related shows this error.

There is my config file:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf; User Instance=false;Integrated Security=false" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="connect" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database2.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: I don't see the error :).  Did you forget to include it?

Comment: @MikeM, I edited, it's mentioned into the title, as well. Thank you for correcting :D

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "InitialCatalog=DatabaseName;" to your connection string:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFileName.mdf;InitialCatalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

Here are [some examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0) from the MSDN website to refer to.